# datastore is gone from Storage but its exist

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have ESXI 5.5 installed on my dedicated server. unfortunately after rebooting the server (hardware reboot/hot reboot) "Datastore2" isn't in Summary --> Storage.
But fortunately "Datastore2" folder exist in this directory : /vmfs/volumes/ and all my VMs are still in "Datastore2" folder! So I'm happy!

But how can use my Datastore2 again? I can't access the VMs on Datastore2.

I tried Configuration -> Storage -> Add Storage but it's gonna format my HDD then Datastore2 and its VMs be removed!

What can I do? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to do a rescan for datastores?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened.

Comment: Is this a locally stored datastore or something like iSCSI or NFS connected thing?

Comment: It's Locally stored datastore

Comment: any ideas? please help

Comment: Well, the best idea i have is to take a look at your vmkernel.log to find out what is the reason of datastore not mounting.

Comment: I took a look at vmkernel.log and found some lines that contain error

Comment: 2016-02-12T05:03:04.079Z cpu15:34484 opID=e40fd3eb)Partition: 423: Failed read for "t10.ATA___mydevice name": I/O error
2016-02-12T05:03:04.079Z cpu15:34484 opID=e40fd3eb)Partition: 1003: Failed to read protective mbr on "t10.ATA___mydevice name" : I/O error
2016-02-12T05:03:04.079Z cpu15:34484 opID=e40fd3eb)WARNING: Partition: 1112: Partition table read from device t10.ATA___mydevice name failed: I/O error

Comment: Looks like and HDD error (hope it is not) or "LUN not ready issue". Take a look here: http://myserverissues.blogspot.com/2015/03/lun-is-not-in-ready-state-at-storage.html

Comment: I got nothing from that link. How should I fix this problem?